# change magento admin nav menu title

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I'm trying to change the name of the main nav title from "CMS" to "Content".  But I'm not sure how to do this w/out touching the core files.  can I override this in my module config file?  or do I do this somewhere else?  This is my first experience w/ magento

```
<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <cms>
            <children>
                <feature translate="title" module="feature">
                    <title>Feature</title>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                </feature>
            </children>
        </cms>
    </menu>
    <acl></acl>
    <events></events>
    <translate></translate>
</adminhtml>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try adding the title element for the cms element. Im pretty sure things share the same core structure at every nesting level of the config...

```
 <menu>
   <cms>
     <title>Content</title>
     <children>
       <feature translate="title" module="feature">
         <title>Feature</title>
         <sort_order>2</sort_order>
       </feature>
      </children>
    </cms>
  </menu>
```

Answer (score 3):

Magento has a built in function available in the Admin to allow you to do this without touching ANY code at all. Why not just enable Translation in the Admin and then you can rename anything you want without changing anything!!

Go to [System] > [Configuration] > [Advanced] > [Developer] > [Translate Inline] and change "Enabled for Admin" to Yes.

When you save a little book icon will show up next to all menu items and most other text.  Click the icon and a popup will show allowing you to rename it to anything you want.  The results are stored in the Magento Translation csv files under your chosen Local and nothing at all is changed in the magento core.  That is how Magento is designed to use translate not by editing the core.

After you are happy with the results turn Translation back off in Admin.  BTW this works for the front end as well so you don't need to spend hours finding what file in your Theme is responsible for the text you want to change!!  :)

Comment: I tried this - the way Magento implements the translate inline feature, doesn't sit at all well with the menu system. As soon as you mouse-over the book icon, it thinks you've moused-out (mouse-outed?) the menu, and it disappears. Looks like half of this is done with onmouseover and onmouseout, and the other half is done with Prototype's Element.observe, so not easily overridden either.